# How to enable to hot-corners function on Lubuntu20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, .desktop

I want to make Lubuntu20.04 enable hot-corner function likes Expose on macOS.
Is there any way to realize it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by *expose* function, so I cannot help your issue as I don't know what you're asking for. Your description as written, or without picture requires a responder to know macOS and I don't sorry.   (*my comment was on the answer as it related to the provided answer*)

Comment: @guiverc Expose function on macOS mean hot-corner function on Ubuntu. Excuse me to make you confuse.

Comment: I'm rather familiar with hot-corner functions since some Linux desktops (KDE 4) have had them for over a decade, but the options are varied and you mention a specific *expose* function that I don't know. Those *user* features tend to use resources, and the L in LXQt is *light* so it's not seen as fitting with the *light* purpose.  Those features also require a tight fit with DM/WM, where as LXQt isn't attached to either (unlike KDE which has them).  *Is it possible, I bet it is, but it'd require a lot of configuration and may need constant tweaking to keep working as upgrades occur I suspect*

Comment: @guiverc I understand. Lubuntu20.04 is a very new distribution, and LXQt is not easy to use hot corners function for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could find, Gnome has adopted hot corner's for their desktop environment. However Lubuntu 20.04 uses LXQt which is meant to be a sleek and light-weight desktop env.

You could install Gnome desktop env. to your Lubuntu and add the Gnome-tweaks extension which seems to allow Hot corners functionality easily.

Edit: My apologies as [guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc) stated the link I provided will be for legacy LXDE Lubuntu, not focal 20.04

It seems that there is hotcorners for LXQt named `tip-skippy` I would further look into this page: [lubuntu tip-skippy article](https://lubuntu.me/tip-skippy/)

Comment: The PPA in that page supports up to Xenial, and was intended for LXDE or legacy Lubuntu, not modern Lubuntu & LXQt.  The commands provided on the page won't work for *focal* / 20.04 though, but thanks for bringing the page to my attention   *the few clues on the page that it's for LXDE could be easily missed*

Comment: @guiverc So you mean there is no way to realize expose like function currently, right?

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command on Ubuntu 20.04 terminal

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners true`

Worked for me. Source: [luanlmd.medium.com](https://luanlmd.medium.com/ubuntu-20-04-enable-hot-corners-82b15b542a8)

Comment: That configuration command assumes GNOME, however Lubuntu 20.04 LTS isn't using GNOME but LXQt.  I booted a Lubuntu 20.04.5 LTS *live* system & tried it, it did nothing.